# geometrically connected fibres, multiplicative group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

If $f: X \to Y$ has geometrically connected fibres, $f_*\mathbb{G}_m = \mathbb{G}_m$ as Zariski sheaves. Does it also hold as étale sheaves?

Comment: Your claim is false even for Zariski topology. Please clarify the hypothesis.